# Replace all characters except letters, numbers and spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem when i use `preg_replace`. I have this code :

```
$title = 'this       $@*$@)(*$)(@*) 89898 is  '  an  "" exemple !!!:';
$titlefinal = preg_replace('/[^ \w]+/', '', $title);
```

This echo's : `this 89898 is 039 an quotquot exemple`

This code shown only the letters and numbers but it shows the '039' for the `'`  and 'quotquot' for the `""`, how can i make my code so only numbers, letters and space whould show up nothing else.

**Found it!**
After another research on stackoverflow i figured this code:

```
$titlefinal = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = preg_replace('/[^\da-z ]/i', '', $title);
```

Comment: still shows the "039" for the ' and for "" shows "quotquot"